# Notation for intersection of functions

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Suppose $f,g : [0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$ are continuous, $f$ is non-decreasing, $g$ is non-increasing, and $f(0)<g(0)$, $f(1)>g(1)$.

Is there a standard notation for the intersection point $x_0$ of $f$ and $g$, defined as $ x_0 = \inf\{ x\in[0,1] : f(x) \geq g(x) \} $?

If so, I would also be interested in a reference, where such notation is used.

Comment: So do you mean $\inf (f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$?

Comment: Yes, but the question is, is there an established notation / symbol for that? Something like $f \cap g$.

Comment: No, I always call it "the first intersection point of $f$ and $g$"...